# order by and group by not working in same query

Tags: mysql

I have following mysql database record in my device_update table...

[image]

now I am running following query to get my records.

```
SELECT u.*,d.device_name 
FROM device_update u 
left join device d on u.device_ip = d.device_ip 
WHERE 1 AND 
      d.status = 'A' 
group by u.device_ip,u.old_version 
order by u.created_at DESC LIMIT 0,20
```

and I am getting this records.

[image]

but I want the second record as id value 3 because it's created_at value is newer than id 2 but I am getting id 3 value. how to do this?

Comment: Also, note that your `Group By` is not valid (ANSI SQL compliant), and newer (stricter) versions of MySQL will throw errors in it.

Comment: Also, Do read: [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3639861/2469308)